# ipython version conflict while installing mermaid and ipykernel using pip

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, ipython, mermaid

In order to use Mermaid in a IPython Notebook I have to install `nb-mermaid` according to [this](https://pypi.org/project/nb-mermaid/0.1.0/). Unfortunately, it uninstall the previous version of installed `ipython` package, which has actually newer version.

```
Installing collected packages: IPython, nb-mermaid
  Attempting uninstall: IPython
    Found existing installation: ipython 8.2.0
    Uninstalling ipython-8.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled ipython-8.2.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
ipykernel 6.11.0 requires ipython>=7.23.1, but you have ipython 3.2.3 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed IPython-3.2.3 nb-mermaid-0.1.0
```

It downgrades `ipython-8.2.0` to `ipython-3.2.3`. And actually there is still an open issue about [this](https://github.com/bollwyvl/nb-mermaid/issues/7).

Then to resolve the problem I try to upgrade the `ipython` package.

```
Installing collected packages: ipython
  Attempting uninstall: ipython
    Found existing installation: ipython 3.2.3
    Uninstalling ipython-3.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled ipython-3.2.3
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
nb-mermaid 0.1.0 requires IPython<4.0,>3.0, but you have ipython 8.2.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed ipython-8.2.0
```

And another problem comes up for dependency of `nb-mermaid`. As summary

| Package | Date | Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `nb-mermaid-0.1.0` | `28 Jul 2015` | `ipython` | `<4.0`, `>3.0` |
| `ipykernel-6.11.0` | `31 Mar 2022` | `ipython` | `>=7.23.1` |

which shows that there is not any overlap version available to install both `nb-mermaid-0.1.0` and `ipykernel-6.11.0`.

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to install `nb-mermaid` according to [this](https://pypi.org/project/nb-mermaid/0.1.0/)

It's no wonder that [that project](https://github.com/bollwyvl/nb-mermaid) includes some very old dependencies: it hasn't been touched in nearly 6 years and has been abandoned by the author. Personally, I'd avoid using it at all.

Unfortunately, I don't see any good modern alternatives on a quick search.

If you really want to use it, I suggest you use the latest commit from the `master` branch where [the `<4.0` constraint on `IPython` was removed](https://github.com/bollwyvl/nb-mermaid/commit/a2c9168d8cb661a1c5517f9f3432ba7f4d9c21a7#diff-6341be4dfdb52ffdfac24972f1ad4cc38cb939111e2b8d0ead789fe0e82f982dL20-R20):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bollwyvl/nb-mermaid.git@103502e6
```

Comment: Thank you, @Chris. And I follow you suggestion not to use the abandoned [nb-mermaid-0.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/nb-mermaid/0.1.0/) and try to search the alternatives. Luckily, I have found [nb-js-diagrammers-0.0.7](https://pypi.org/project/nb-js-diagrammers/0.0.7/), which supports Mermaid.js and also flowchart.js, wavedrom, waversurfer.js. It is still maintained and works.